# Entity Framework OrderBy on field from projection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dto

I want to sort on a field only known at runtime, and that field may be constructed inside the `select` clause.

Requirements:

1. User should be able to sort on any column;
2. That column may come from an entity or projection class;
3. Programmer decides if want to return the same source entity, or a projection.

Because of (3), straightforward implementation wouldn't find a field from projection class, as I have a static type of the base/entity type. Then I began to change code to consider the resulting type instead.

I have a feeling that it is just static typing getting in the way, that is not really helping here. Unfortunately `IQueryable<dynamic>` doesn't work.

Sample code (details omitted for brevity):

```
void Main()
{
    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        var original = db.Set<Sample>();

        // requirement (3), static type Sample, dynamic type SampleDTO
        Expression<Func<Sample, Sample>> fn = item => new SampleDTO() { Description = "Value: " + item.Name};
        var projected = original.Select(fn);

        // requirements (1) and (2)
        var ordered = OrderBy_Default<Sample, SampleDTO>(projected, "Description");
        ordered.Dump();
    }
}

private IQueryable<T> OrderBy_Default<T, TProject>(IQueryable<T> source, string ordering)
{
  var type = source.ElementType;
  var resultType = type;
  var property = resultType.GetProperty(ordering, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
  var parameter = Expression.Parameter(resultType, "p");
  var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
  var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
  MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
      "OrderBy",
      new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
      source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
  return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
}
```

The previous code produces this error:

> No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

I have tried `projected.Cast<SampleDTO>()`:

> Unable to cast the type 'Sample' to type 'UserQuery+SampleDTO'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

I have tried `projected.OfType<SampleDTO>()`:

> 'UserQuery+SampleDTO' is not a valid metadata type for type filtering operations. Type filtering is only valid on entity types and complex types.

`Cast()` and `OfType()` works with L2O, but not with L2EF.

Adding `SampleDTO` to entity model of course is not the answer (have tried it though, for the sake of knowing how it would work).

My entities & projections:

```
public class Sample
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SampleDTO: Sample
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I made SampleDTO inherit from Sample, it case it helps. That's is not a requirement, it's a matter of convenience.

**Some possible answer:**

Instead of `Expression<Func<Sample, Sample>>` I could have `Expression<Func<Sample, SampleDTO>>`. That invalidates requirement (3) and would break much of my existing code.

PS: I'm considering using the Microsoft Dynamic LINQ library, but for the sake of the answer I'm looking forward to know what's really going on.

Comment: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Dynamic/DynamicQueryable.cs This can help you.

Comment: Same results: "ParseException: No property or field 'Description' exists in type 'Sample'"

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me, if i understand your question correctly but i get the feeling i am missing something

```
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var property = type.GetProperty(ordering);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type);
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
    }
```

Comment: `T` is Sample, then it would fail saying that "Description" is not defined on that type.